# Does Python optimise away duplicate expressions in list comprehensions?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, list-comprehension

Consider the following list comprehension:

```
[s.strip() for s in ['a', 'b ', ' ', ' c'] if s.strip()]
```

Would `s.strip()` be computed twice, or would Python optimise such expressions internally and compute duplicate expressions only once? I know that Python is not a compiled language, but such a simple optimisation could even be inferred from the AST.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A quick look at https://python-ast-explorer.com/ suggests this does not get optimized. `str` is called inside the GeneratorExp and again in the generator.

Comment: "I know that Python is not a compiled language" => There's nothing like a "compiled language" - a language is a grammar and syntax, period. You can write a C interpreter, and you could write a compiler for Python - [if it didn't exist already](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html), surprise surprise, CPython IS compiled (to bytecode).

Comment: "such a simple optimisation could even be inferred from the AST." => the stdlib's exposes all the language's internals (including the AST), and the CPython implementation is OSS, so if it's such a "simple optimisation" please implement it and send a merge request, you'll be more than welcome ;-) But the issue is not about compilation, it's about the execution model and the highly dynamic nature of Python, which makes some "simple optimisations" not that simple...

Comment: As a side note: try `filter(None, [s.strip() for s in ['a', 'b ', ' ', ' c'])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Is `s.strip()` called twice?

If you use CPython, yes. You can try the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) to cehck the bytecode.

```
def f():
    return [s.strip() for s in ['a', 'b ', ' ', ' c'] if s.strip()]
```

With Python 3.7, you get the bytecode of the function and the list comprehension:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)

  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7f6ddc8ce8a0, file "temp.py", line 2>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f.<locals>.<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (('a', 'b ', ' ', ' c'))
              8 GET_ITER
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x7f6ddc8ce8a0, file "temp.py", line 2>:
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                20 (to 26)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (s)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (s)
             10 LOAD_METHOD              0 (strip)
             12 CALL_METHOD              0
             14 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        4
             16 LOAD_FAST                1 (s)
             18 LOAD_METHOD              0 (strip)
             20 CALL_METHOD              0
             22 LIST_APPEND              2
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   26 RETURN_VALUE
```

(With Python <= 3.6, you have to write `dis.dis(f.__code__.co_consts[1])` to get the bytecode of the list comprehension.)

As you see, the method `strip` is called twice (line 10-12 and 18-20).

## Why Cpython does not make this optimisation?

> such a simple optimisation could even be inferred from the AST.

Why do you expect `s.strip()` to be computed once? Because you known that this function is [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) and especially that if `s == t`, then `s.strip() == t.strip()`. But there is, to the extent of my knowledge, no such concept in Python. That means that the interpreter has no way to say that the result will be the same.

A little example with a non pure function (yes, this is ugly):

```
>>> i=0
>>> def mystrip(s):
...     global i
...     i+=1
...     return s.strip() if i%2==0 else s
...
```

One call, `mystrip` returns the stripped string, the other, it returns the string:

```
>>> mystrip('a ')
'a '
>>> mystrip('a ')
'a'
```

Hence the following result:

```
>>> [mystrip(s) for s in ['a', 'b ', ' ', ' c'] if mystrip(s)]
['a', 'b', '', 'c']
```

`if` arguments are not stripped (hence `True` because all the string have at least one char), but the returned values are stripped.

## Manual optimisation

If you want `s.strip()` to be evaluated once, you have to write:

```
>>> [t for t in (s.strip() for s in ['a', 'b ', ' ', ' c']) if t]
```

(The expression between parentheses is a generator.)

Other versions (see also @bruno desthuilliers comment under our question):

```
>>> [t for t in map(str.strip, ['a', 'b ', ' ', ' c']) if t]
>>> list(filter(None, (s.strip() for s in ['a', 'b ', ' ', ' c'])))
>>> filter(None, map(str.strip, ['a', 'b ', ' ', ' c']))
```